# Passing variables in Sencha

Tags: dom, extjs, pass-by-reference

In Sencha in a child window I obtain an id of an image, how can I then pass the image id to a text field in a parent window. I go to the child window with a button click, and would like to display the id of the chosen image in a text field above the button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would pass a textfield reference to the window during window creation, and when the button is clicked, you use that reference:

```
    xtype: 'textfield',
},{
    xtype:'button',
    text: 'Get Image'
    handler: function(btn) {
        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
            textfieldReference: btn.previousSibling('textfield'),
            buttons:[{
                text: 'OK',
                handler: function(okBtn) {
                    okBtn.up('window').textfieldReference.setValue(imageId);
                }
            }]
        })
    }
```